# Store all iteration loop results in a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, iteration

I have a code that basically selects some data segements and performs some calculations on these data segments (regression lines, so I look at the slope and the intercept of the resgression lines). The code works fine and at the end it displays in the Command window the results of all the loop iterations but it only sotres in a matrix (called final) the last loop iteration results. Basically I would like to have all the results in a matrix.

Here i attach the code:

```
Data = csvread(inputFile);

for i=1:max(L)
try
B = [ones(length(result{i}),1) result{i}(:,1)] \ result{i}(:,2);
catch
    continue 
end


intercept = B(1);
slope  = B(2);
position  = (slope.*result{i}(end,1)+intercept)-(slope .*result{i}(1:1)+intercept);
time = result{i}(end,1)-result{i}(1:1);

final =[slope, intercept, position, time] 

end
```

At the moment I get the result of each loop in the command window. So i obtain something like this:

```
final =

   4.6607  -27.7973    0.0621    0.0133


final =

   -0.0647   -0.1299   -0.0517    0.7992


final =

   -9.0676   74.6981   -0.0604    0.0067


final =

   0.3176   -3.2234    0.0698    0.2198


final =

   0.2153   -2.3666    0.0631    0.2930


final =

   -5.1864   45.6418   -0.2072    0.0400


final =

   -1.0881    9.1772   -0.0797    0.0733


final =

   -0.5416    4.3386   -0.1605    0.2964


final =

   -4.4898   39.8786   -1.2409    0.2764


final =

   -3.0985   26.3052   -0.0619    0.0200


final =

   2.0871  -24.2849    0.0208    0.0100


final =

   1.0060  -15.6203    0.0067    0.0067
```

How can I get all this in a matrix?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When displaying lots of MATLAB command window output, it is best to use `format compact`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#inputarg_Style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final(i,:) =[slope, intercept, position, time];
```

Pre-allocate your array before the `for` loop:

```
final = zeros(max(L),4);
```

Answer (score -1):

This helped me in 2016!!

My problem was similar, but simpler: here is my code and how helped me:

```
tic
clear all; clc; 

 A = [1 1 1 0 0; 1 0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 1]
 b = [1; 1; 1];
[m,n] = size(A)

Puntos_extremos = factorial(n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m));
fprintf('Puntos_extremos = %d\n\n', Puntos_extremos);

permut = [1:n];
P = nchoosek(permut,m);

xx = zeros(Puntos_extremos,n);
for i=1:Puntos_extremos
    B  = A(:,P(i,:));
 if det(B) == 0
    fprintf('x%d^T =',i); fprintf('La submatriz B es singular\n')
 else 

     x_B= B\b;
    x_N = zeros(2,1);
    x = [x_B;x_N];
    fprintf('x%d^T =',i); fprintf('%4d', x'); fprintf('\n');

 end


% Here i got your help. Thanks bot of you!!
 xx(i,:) = x;
end

VectFAct = xx

toc
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In addition to providing your code, make sure you include some text that explains what and why your code helps to answer the OP.